# UITableView didSelectRowAt returns wrong tableViewCell at indexPath

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I a making a todo plan app, and I have encountered a serious bug in my tableViewCell. Whenever I select a row more than once, the wrong indexPath at row is called.

If I comment out my `resultsController.delegate` the app works normally. However I need the results controller delegate for to update the table view every time a new plan is made.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create Request
    let request:NSFetchRequest<Plan> = Plan.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptors = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true) // make request more specific
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptors]

    // Init our results controller
    resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: request,
        managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil
    )
    resultsController.delegate = self

    // Perform fetch request
    do {
        try resultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Perform fetch error \(error)")
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant **TableViewDelegates**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNewPlan", sender: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
}
```

Also i have also added my prepare function for navigation.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let _ = sender as? UIBarButtonItem , let vc = segue.destination as? NewPlanViewController {
        vc.managedContext = resultsController.managedObjectContext
    }
    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell , let vc = segue.destination as? NewPlanViewController {
        vc.managedContext = resultsController.managedObjectContext
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            let plan = resultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            vc.plan = plan
        }
    }
}
```

The `resultsControllerDelegate` is how I update my `tableViewCells`.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            let plan = resultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = plan.title
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: You havinng issues with `UITableView` and not showing any code of it. Could you please code affecting the `UITableView`?

Comment: You should show `UITableViewDelegate` functions like `didSelectRowAtIndex` and others.

Comment: I am very grateful for your early replies. @flyingBear i have included {UITableViewDelegate} functions in the new edit of the question.